# Custom Type FrameWork in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I have created one Custom type Frame work, and that frame work i added in to my app, in that custom frame work i added simple method, that will return the normal string, But my question is i want to use that framework as a API calls like login and registration and all, i used NSJSONSERIALIZATION for fetch data from json, it will return the values, but i want to use that data in my app, can any one tell me , i am very new in custom type Frameworks and all;

```
-(void )JsonData :(NSDictionary *)dictionary method:(NSString *)method url:(NSString *)url {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];

    NSLog(@"apiCall RequestUrl: %@, HTTPMethod: %@, RequestData: %@", request.URL.absoluteString, method, dictionary);

    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"] || [method isEqualToString:@"PUT"])
    {
        NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:(NSDictionary *)dictionary options:0 error:nil];
        [request setHTTPBody:dataToSend];
    }



    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *responseError)
     {
         NSDictionary *responseData;

         if (responseError)
         {
             responseData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Error", @"status",
                             responseError.localizedDescription, @"message",
                             nil];
         }
         else if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] != 200)
         {
             responseData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Error", @"status",
                             @"Invalid Response from server.", @"message",
                             nil];
         }
         else if ([[Response getCustomStatus:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response] isEqualToString:@"invalid_session"])
         {
             responseData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Error", @"status",
                             @"Your session has been expired.", @"message",
                             nil];
         }
         else
         {
             responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&responseError];
         }

         NSLog(@"apiCall ResponseData: %@", responseData);


         CustomerInfo *customer = [[CustomerInfo alloc]init];
         customer.session = [[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"session"];
         NSLog(@"JsonData:%@",[[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"session"]);
         NSLog(@"Data:%@",customer.session);
         customer.groupID = [[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"group_id"];
         NSLog(@"%@",[[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"group_id"]);
         NSLog(@"Data:%@", customer.groupID );

         customer.cutomerID = [[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"customer_id"];
         NSLog(@"%@",[[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"customer_id"]);
         NSLog(@"Data:%@", customer.cutomerID );

         customer.stylistProfilepicUrl = [[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"stylist_profile_url"];
         NSLog(@"%@",[[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"stylist_profile_url"]);
         NSLog(@"Data:%@", customer.stylistProfilepicUrl);

         customer.fbUserID = [[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"fb_user_id"];
         NSLog(@"%@",[[[responseData objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"fb_user_id"]);
         NSLog(@"Data:%@", customer.fbUserID );

     }];
}
```

This is my Frame Work code,

in my app i jsut call this code and send the parameters,

i got the response,but while i am printing the data, it showing null values in my app,

Can any one suggest me or send me any link or tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting valid data, then log

```
NSLog(@"apiCall ResponseData: %@", responseData.description);
```

Check and try to print any error.description probably in the last else part